# Как можно реализовать логику открытия и закрытия popup на react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, popup

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { GlobalSvgSelector } from '../../../assets/Images/icons/global/GlobalSvgSelector';
import { Item } from '../../../pages/Home/components/ThisDayInfo/ThisDayInfo';
import { ThisDayItem } from '../../../pages/Home/components/ThisDayInfo/ThisDayItem';
import style from './Popup.module.scss';

interface Props {}

export const Popup = ({}: Props) => {
  const items = [
    {
      icon_id: 'temp',
      name: 'Температура',
      value: '20° - ощущается как 17°',
    },
    {
      icon_id: 'pressure',
      name: 'Давление',
      value: '765 мм ртутного столба - нормальное',
    },
    {
      icon_id: 'precipitation',
      name: 'Осадки',
      value: 'Без осадков',
    },
    {
      icon_id: 'wind',
      name: 'Ветер',
      value: '3 м/с юго-запад - легкий ветер',
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <div className={style.blur}></div>
      <div className={style.popup}>
        <div className={style.day}>
          <div className={style.day_temp}>20°</div>
          <div className={style.day_name}>Среда</div>
          <div className={style.img}>
            <GlobalSvgSelector id="sun" />
          </div>
          <div className={style.day_time}>
            Время: <span>21:54</span>
          </div>
          <div className={style.day_city}>
            Город: <span>Минск</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={style.this_day_info_items}>
          {items.map((item: Item) => (
            <ThisDayItem key={item.icon_id} item={item} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className={style.close}>
          <GlobalSvgSelector id="close" />
        </div>`введите сюда код`
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а чем не подходит уже имеющийся код?

Comment: поп ап не закрывается и не открывается,он просто висит на странице,задумывалось сделать чтоб по нажатию он и открывался и закрывался

Comment: по нажатию куда?

Comment: открывался на само тело попапа,а закрывался на иконку крестика,мне нужна буквально функция,без лишних нпмов

Comment: если тело попапа показывается - разве это не значит, что он уже открыт?

Comment: не,он при загрузке самой страницы так стоит,он статичен

Comment: ну так если он показывается - значит от открыт? Или что ты понимаешь под "открытием" тогда?

Comment: он изначально открыт при загрузке самой страницы,а мне нужно чтоб он открывался при наведении и клику на элемент,а закрывался на клик по крестику,могу скинуть ссылку на репозиторий чтоб проще понималось

Comment: просто добавляй или удаляй компонент меняя значение стейта

Comment: а можешь показать как это должно выглядеть, просто пока не совсем правильно понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: заводишь переменную в стейте. и проверяешь ее `{flag && <Popup />}`. Соответственно, поставишь флаг false - попап уберется, поставишь true - показывается

Comment: через функцию проверять?

Comment: в комментарии вышепример

Comment: можешь ещё подсказать,смотри,у меня поп ап остался таким же статичным что и был только что фон сзади становится при каждом клике чернее, но сам поп ап при этом не двигается,нужно ли создавать какой то второй файл чтоб прописать ему действия ,и если надо,то что там нужно прописать?

Comment: @Асфиксия, нужно смотреть код, который у тебя сейчас. Причина в чем угодно может быть. Например не там флаг заведен, или убираешь не тот компонент, или не по тому событию ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: https://github.com/asphyxiadeath/diplom-project
ссылка на гит,буду вечным должником если выручишь
(там пока мешанина и сборная солянка с логикой попапа,но с большего понятно)